# Lists Posts from CPT that match the Title of the Page

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, loop

I am trying to get all the posts associated with the Title of a page.

This is what I currently have:

```
    <?php
        $title_to_tag_posts_query = new WP_Query( array(
        'tag' => get_queried_object()->post_name 
        ) );

        while ( $title_to_tag_posts_query->have_posts() ) : $title_to_tag_posts_query->the_post(); ?>
        <p>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        <?php the_date(); ?>
        </p>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

It works in pulling all the posts where the tag matches the title of the Page. Except, it doesn't work with posts under a custom post type, even though they are tagged.  So I almost have it, but not quite. I'm still missing content from the CPT posts.

I've been playing around with it by using some conditionals but all I seem to do is break it. The CPT I am trying to get the posts from has the `capability_type` of 'post' so I'm pretty sure that's not the problem.  I think I just may be missing the proper conditional or appropriate way to query for this?

Comment: You need to either add your CPT to the WP_Query `'post_type'` arg or set it to `'any'`, eg `'post_type' => 'any'`.

Comment: And here I was trying to write if statements and such.  I overlook the dumbest things that are written in the codex sometimes.  Thanks a ton

Answer (score 0):

By default [`wp_query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Type_Parameters) returns posts of type 'post' only, unless `tax_query` is set. So you would have to set `'post_type' => array( 'post', 'your-cpt-name' )` to get posts from your CPT as well.

You can set the `post_type` to `any` as well, but that will also return other post types, such as attachments that might have the same tag.